# Insert operation failed: c#, sql server

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I am trying to insert into my table Add_Product, but it is not working.That its not getting into the database, neither showing any error
This is my connection class:

```
 public static class ConnectionClass
    {
        private static SqlConnection con;
        private static SqlCommand cmd;

        static ConnectionClass()
        {
            string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        }

        public static void AddProduct(Product product)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Add_Product (Party, Product_Name, Price, Quantity,Type,Details,Date) values (@Party, @Product_Name, @Price,Quantity,@Type,@Details, @Date,)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Party", product.Party);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Name", product.Product_Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", product.Price);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", product.Quantity);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", product.Type);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Details", product.Quantity);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", product.Date);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }

            finally
            {

                con.Close();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

This is Product class constructor:

```
 public Product(string Party, string Product_Name, double Price, int Quantity, string Type, string Details, string Date)
        {
            this.Party = Party;
            this.Product_Name = Product_Name;
            this.Price = Price;
            this.Quantity = Quantity;
            this.Type = Type;
            this.Details = Details;
            this.Date = Date;
        }
```

And the code behind is:

```
 protected void btnAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string Party = TbPartyName.Text;
                string Name = TbProdName.Text;
                double Price = Convert.ToDouble(TbPrice.Text);
                int Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(TbQuantity.Text);
                string Type = TbType.Text;
                string Details = TbDetail.Text;
                string Date = TbDate.Text;

                Product product = new Product(Party, Name, Price, Quantity, Type, Details, Date);
                ConnectionClass.AddProduct(product);
                lblAdd.Text = "Added succesfully";
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                lblAdd.Text = "Operation Failed";
            }

        }
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: What are the details of the exception that is being caught?

Comment: "@Date, "       after date you have additional comma

Comment: That's the reason why you should debug your code first..

Comment: Oops too many syntax errors. My bad. its working fine now. And really sorry for my stupidities! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed this excerpt from your insert statement:

> @Price,Quantity,@Type

See that "Quantity" is missing the `@` character?

---

Also: see @Usman Butt's comment: there is an extra comma at the end of the query.

Comment: Very good eye my friend!

Comment: Oops too many syntax errors. My bad. its working fine now. And really sorry for my stupidities! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try this insert query...`@quantity and remove comma after @date`

> cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Add_Product (Party, Product_Name, Price, Quantity,Type,Details,Date) values (@Party, @Product_Name, @Price,@Quantity,@Type,@Details, @Date)", con);

Answer (score 0):

you've put extra comma after @Date parameter in query. There is no error because you put command's ExecuteNonQuery method to try clause and never caught with exception clause.